# Dataset retrieving again

Tags: c#, dataset

Is it possible to retrieve an already filled of data `Dataset`? Sample I filled dataset "`Customer`" from a `form1`, Then I want to retrieve again the the dataset "`Customer`" in `form2` without doing the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DataSet` property on the second form and pass the values from `form1`'s dataset to this property.

```
public class Form1
{
    public DataSet ds;

    // You have already filled your DataSet so I'll leave that code out
    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.MyDataSet = ds;
        frm.Show();
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    public DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how? ... just a newbie on C#

Comment: ohh i get... :D.. how bout when datatable?... a premade datatable... (premade = i just Add item datatable in visual studio)...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Form1
{
    private DataSet _myDataSet;
    // do things
    private void fillMyDataSet()
    {
        //fill your dataset
    }
    public dataSet GetMyDataSet()
    {
        if(_myDataSet != null)
            return _myDataSet;
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

then in your form 2 all you have to do is something like:

```
DataSet myOtherDataSet = Form1.GetMyDataSet();
```

Comment: oh...like getter and setter...will it also work on a modified dataset?...like when i 1st retrieve a dataset...iv'e deleted some rows and edit it.....and also...the dataset was made not programatically... like i add new Item on Visual studio..

Comment: it should work yes on a modified dataset, just assign the _myDataSet to your have the value of the dataset you added.

Comment: ohh...so in a datatable... (premade)iv'e named it lets say JODT...so how do i declare it?

Comment: after you filled your datatable jodt just declare `_myDataTable = JODT;`

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a property of `Form1` and pass the instance of `Form1` to `Form2`:

```
public class Form1:Form 
{
    public DataSet Data { get; set; }

    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 child = new Form2(this);
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 parent) { Parent = parent; }
    public Form1 Parent { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // now you can use the DataSet of Form1 via Parent proprty:
        DataSet data = this.Parent.Data;
    }
}
```